# No access to internet from DMZ Cisco ASA 5512

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Glad to join the forum. I hope to get help too and help as much as I can. Currently I have a big problem. I am using Cisco ASA 5512. I defined 3 interfaces on the firewall: inside (192.168.0.0), outside (192.198.100.253) and DMZ (192.168.1.0) which includes web servers and other VPN sevices. The DMZ can not access the internet, despite everything I think I have done. Can more experienced people and specialists help me?
Here is the firewall configuration
Thank you

```
: Saved
:
ASA Version 9.1(2)
!
hostname ciscoasa

enable password HiGcJ9e0GTkEROyY encrypted

passwd WixegyNLwa6OgUk7 encrypted

names

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0

 nameif outside

 security-level 0

 ip address 192.168.100.253 255.255.255.0

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/1

 nameif inside

 security-level 100

 ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/2

 nameif dmz

 security-level 50

 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/3

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address

!

interface GigabitEthernet0/4

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address

!

interface Management0/0

 management-only

 nameif management

 security-level 100

 ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0

!

ftp mode passive

same-security-traffic permit inter-interface

same-security-traffic permit intra-interface

object network INSIDE-LAN-SUBNET

 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0

object network DMZ-LAN-SUBNET

 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network dmz

 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0

object network webserver-IP_MTN

 host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

object network webserver

 host 192.168.1.103

access-list outside_acl extended permit tcp any object webserver eq www


access-list dmz_access_in extended permit ip any 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0


access-list dmz_access_in extended permit ip 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0

pager lines 24

logging asdm informational

mtu outside 1500

mtu inside 1500

mtu dmz 1500

mtu management 1500

no failover

icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1

no asdm history enable

arp timeout 14400

no arp permit-nonconnected

!

object network INSIDE-LAN-SUBNET

 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface

object network DMZ-LAN-SUBNET

 nat (dmz,outside) dynamic interface

object network webserver

 nat (dmz,outside) static webserver-IP_MTN service tcp www www

access-group outside_acl in interface outside

access-group dmz_access_in in interface dmz

route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.100.254 1

timeout xlate 3:00:00

timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30

timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02

timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00

timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00

timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute

timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00

timeout floating-conn 0:00:00

dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy

user-identity default-domain LOCAL

http server enable

http 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 management

no snmp-server location

no snmp-server contact

snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart

crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite

crypto ca trustpool policy

telnet timeout 5

ssh timeout 5

ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1

console timeout 0

dhcpd address 192.168.0.2-192.168.0.99 inside

dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 interface inside

dhcpd lease 86400 interface inside

dhcpd domain savannah.local interface inside

!
threat-detection basic-threat

threat-detection statistics access-list

no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept

tftp-server inside 192.168.2.254 \\SaveConfigCisco\aa

!
class-map inspection_default

 match default-inspection-traffic

!

!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map

 parameters

  message-length maximum client auto

  message-length maximum 512

policy-map global_policy

 class inspection_default

  inspect dns preset_dns_map

  inspect ftp

  inspect h323 h225

  inspect h323 ras

  inspect rsh

  inspect rtsp

  inspect esmtp

  inspect sqlnet

  inspect skinny

  inspect sunrpc

  inspect xdmcp

  inspect sip

  inspect netbios

  inspect tftp

  inspect ip-options

  inspect icmp
!

service-policy global_policy global

prompt hostname context

no call-home reporting anonymous

Cryptochecksum:4105b5919bbb530e69adc84f75dff135

: end
```

Comment: If you simulate traffic using packet-tracer, what does it say?  Like, if you do `packet-tracer input DMZ tcp 192.168.1.100 1234 8.8.8.8 80` does it say it's being blocked or allowed, and hitting the right statements Along the way?

Comment: HI dear Jesse when I simulate as you suggested, the packet still droped  Action: drop
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule

Comment: Hi Jesse.
My apologies for the delay. I was sent out of the office.
When I simulate as you proposed, the package is always dropped:  Action: drop
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-read your ACLs.  Sorry I didn't catch it before but, you're missing statements to allow you to get to public IPs.  All you've currently got are rules to allow you to get to other private IPs.

Just add:

```
object-group service HTTP_HTTPS
 service-object tcp destination eq 80
 service-object tcp destination eq 443

access-list dmz_access_in extended permit HTTP_HTTPS 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 any
```

It should work after that if your route statement is correct and you are truly using another private IP as your next hop.  If that's wrong or this just doesn't work, you will need to provide a diagram of how your equipment is connected and what your public IPs, mask, and gateway are (as provided by your ISP).

Comment: Yes I'm trying to add the commands I will let you know

Comment: Superb. It works. At first I only allowed HTTP-HTTPS. I also allowed ip, and it worked. congratulations and thank you and thank you very much.

Comment: @Jean-LouisK. Sure. Adjust it as needed.  If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer and upvote it.